# How to convert the following method to asynchronous method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I need to convert this method to asynchronous method.

```
public User GetUserByID(int id)
 {
    return  _unitofwork.UserRepository.FindByCondition(u => u.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
 }
```

This is how I change the code.

```
public async Task<User> GetUserByID(int id)
 {
    return await _unitofwork.UserRepository.FindByCondition(u => u.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
 }
```

but `.FirstOrDefault()` or `.FirstOrDefaultAsync()` cannot use there.I only need to return single user. Can anyone point me to right direction?

```
'Task<IEnumerable<User>>' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault' and no accessible extension method 'FirstOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<IEnumerable<User>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [JobsPortal]
```

**Edit- Sorry. My bad, minor mistake.** 
I should have use code like this.

```
public async Task<User> GetUserByID(int id)
 {
    return (await _unitofwork.UserRepository.FindByCondition(u => u.Id == id)).FirstOrDefault();
 }
```

Comment: maybe this will be usefull https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/dn220208(v%3Dvs.113)

Comment: What is the implementation of `FindByCondition` method? When you make some method async you need to change all dependent method calls async to achieve truly non blocking async code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like `FindByCondition` is an asynchronous method itself.

You just need some extra brackets in there so you `await` the result from `FindByCondition` before you call `FirstOrDefault()` on it.

```
return (await _unitofwork.UserRepository.FindByCondition(u => u.Id == id)).FirstOrDefault();
```

The way you had it, it was trying to call `FirstOrDefault` on the `Task` returned from `FindByCondition` without awaiting it.